# CiviMail click through links and Browse Site button not working.

Tags: civimail, click-through

We are running Civi 4.7.22 on WordPress 4.8.1. 
We are having a problem with CiviMail.  I have included a link to a MP4 demo video to highlight what is happening.  Please watch for what happens when I click the "Browse Server" button and when I run the Preview and click the link in the preview. 
We have contacted our host and they assured us that nothing in the server is blocking or restricting those php functions.  I suspect it is a path issue, but I don't know where to look or how to resolve it.
Please see link to video below.
Thank you

http://meatcuttersclub.org/demomp4.mp4

Comment: Is nobody familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved with much much back and forth with our host.    I noticed this issue is all over the forum with no solution, so finally here is the solution: If anyone runs into this issue in the future, check your permissions for /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/url.php  The permissions should be 755. For some reason, ours was 775.  As soon as we changed it to 755 the problem was solved.